# jsonp result is not a function

Tags: javascript, jsonp, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers and I am using jsonp to retrieve some external data.  However, when I get the data back it gives me this error:

```
OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry[3] is not a function
```

My returned data looks like this when it fails:

```
OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry[3]({"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [
]}
)
```

The funny things is, it doesn't fail everytime... Only randomly.  In this instance, only the `[3]` call failed while the rest of `[0]` through `[10]` worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue at the moment. It doesn't seem to happen if I use the openlayers.debug.js. I use v2.12. drawing the map and also initializing the layers (and thus also the script protocol) happens on document load, so @tracevipin loading times can't be it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the exact issue in your case, but usually this happens when the script containing the callback function has not been loaded completely before the response comes.